# Is it too early to think about Christmas?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

I received an odd present today in a shiny red wrap. I was a little surprised as it was no where near Christmas yet but excited at the same time. I tried to tear the present open but was unable to do so. I looked at the back of the present and I found a letter attached to it. I managed to open the envelope read the letter and this is what it said:

Dear Alex, if you guess the item and the person who sent you it, say it out loud and then the present will be yours...Here are the clues which are in no specific order:

1. A Grid
2. 314697,72964,7193,8231,72964

And

3. 713649,13971,179,3146479,73519

Good luck and I hope you have a fun time working this out.

So can you please help me work this out so I can get the present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> ROLEX

Explanation:

> The grid in Clue 1 refers to the keypad you can find on your phone or laptop. 
>  
>  Each number in Clue 2 and Clue 3 traces out the path you need to take on the keypad and will reveal a letter. Join the letters together to form a word. 
>  
>  Clue 2 reveals the name of the sender, which is SANTA. Clue 3 reveals the gift, which is ROLEX.

Comment: Well that was quick, I thought it might take a while, oh well.

Comment: Yo have a crack at my riddle

Comment: @Deepthinker101 The "putting the pieces" one? I've been trying that one for hours lol.

Comment: Lol that is funny, I thought that one was easier than this one